# Using JavaScript to populate the content in a div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've tried a few ways of doing this, the problem is our site is within a custom built CMS that won't allow us to use anything other than HTML and some JavaScript (it's very picky).

What I need to do is have a page within the CMS replace the content of one div on the page with the content of an outside php page.

Here's the code I'm currently using:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$.ajax({
    url: "http://website.com/files/table.php",
    success: function(response){
        $("#budget").append(response);
    }
});

</script>


<div id="budget"></div>
```

The sole content on the php page is a huge table (content being populated from a DB table). Inside the CMS that does not yield anything (literally blank), but on my test html page (not within the CMS) it works just fine. Does anyone know of any other possible solutions working with these types of restraints?

Comment: Are the pages in the same domain? Ajax is crabby about crossing domains.

Comment: Technically it's a subdomain - Would that make a difference?

Comment: Add console.log( response ); to your success function and see what you get. Also run console.log( jQuery ); and console.log( jQuery('#budget') ); in chrome developer tools console or Firebug console to make sure everything you need is getting to the page.

Comment: @cfox -- yes it makes a difference

Comment: @cfox: Yes, a subdomain is not valid to fetch from another (sub)domain.

Comment: @cfox: Yes, it would. Subdomains are blocked by the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

Comment: @brokenindexfinger - I've never debugged JavaScript and have no idea what you are talking about. I placed the "console.log( response );" below the success function, and nothing showed.

Comment: @cfox: You can make a PHP file on your domain, that calls the PHP on the sub-domain, a proxy of sorts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
$("#budget").load("http://website.com/files/table.php");
```

or

a fragment from the table.php response

```
$("#budget").load("http://website.com/files/table.php #fragment");
```

Comment: Didn't work either, although I think it's because the code is on a subdomain. Trying to figure out how to get it on the same domain...

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this with jquery (http://jquery.com/)

```
<script  type='text/javascript'>
 $.get("table.php", function (data) //gets the code behind the page
  { 
     $("#budget").html(data); //places the data in the budget div
  });
</script>
```

Comment: If it's `.html`, you could as well look into `.load`.

Comment: Tried, same result, no content.